# JPA ManyToMany Composite Key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, mapping

Iam designing a small app for myself to get to know JPA and hibernate and Iam looking for some best practices.

Now I have a ManyToMany relationship between my entities `User` and `Group` with `UserGroup` to map them together. My Entity `UserGroup` has an attribute `isGroupAdmin`, which is why I had to model the relationship with an additional entity.

I got everything to work, but I doubt that my solution is performant and I would love to get some input on optimization. For simplicity, I only post the neccessary attributes:

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Userdata")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "Id", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = "Username", columnDefinition = "nvarchar(30)", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String username;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
      orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<UserGroup> userGroups;

  // ----- Getters, Setters, Constructor and equals/hash ommitted for readability
```

Group

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Groups")
public class Group {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "Id", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
      orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<UserGroup> groupUsers;

  // ----- Getters, Setters, Constructor and equals/hash ommitted for readability
```

UserGroup

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_group")
public class UserGroup {

  @PrePersist
  private void prePersist() {
    if (getId() == null) {
      GroupAdminKey pk = new GroupAdminKey();
      pk.setUserId(user.getId());
      pk.setGroupId(group.getId());
      id = pk;
    }
  }

  @EmbeddedId
  GroupAdminKey id;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("userId")
  private User user;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("groupId")
  private Group group;

  private boolean isGroupAdmin;

  @PreRemove
  private void synchronizeRelations() {
    group.getGroupUsers().remove(this);
    user.getUserGroups().remove(this);
  }
```

Now I could add a `User` to a `Group` and also a `Group` to a `User`. I can get all my `Users` by providing a `Group` and vice versa. Same goes for deleting `Users` from a `Group` and vice versa.
I could also get them by querieng my `UserGroup` entity, or even delete the relation via `UserGroup`.

Iam also not very happy with using `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`. As I understand, one of the key advantages of Hibernate is the Lazy-Load functionality that gets under the wheel here a bit.

Finally my Questions are:
1) How should I access my entities? (I could add a `Group` to a `User` providing a new `UserGroup` or I could add a `User` to a `group` providing a new `UserGroup`)

2) What could I do to get rid of the eager fetching on my `User` and `Group` mapping?

3) Should I limit the data access to one of my entities `User` or `Group` or even `UserGroup`?

Thanks for sharing your knowledge ;)

**--Edit**

I have decided to handle the relation between `User` and `Group` via `UserGroup` because I wanted to have a single point of access.

The only problem is that I if I add a new `User` - `Group` relation I cant persist it through `UserGroup` since they are detached. I tried to add the new `UserGroup` to my `User` and `Group` entity in the lifecycle hook `@PrePersist` but that didnt work. Any suggestions how I could manage to get this working?

Comment: "I doubt that my solution is performant" - have you profiled your application? What is the reason for your doubts? Is there an excessive number of roundtrips, slow load time, ...? If it works functionally, I think you can have more confidence in yourself until you've got some figures to prove that your code is 'underperforming' (and relative to what - it's not like your example is especially complicated?)

Comment: More or less an intuition since I dont have that much experience and I pulled bits from various tutorials. I do have sql-statements enabled in my spring boot config. A simple operation like adding a `User` to a `Group` lead to ~17 sql queries (my guess is the eager-fetch which is why I would like to get rid of it). Though the steps are quite simple: (1) Get the `Group` (2) Get the `User` (3) Create a `UserGroup` (4) Add the `UserGroup` to `user.userGroups` (5) Save the `User` entity